# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un archivo excel en un iframe?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp

**Un saludo para todos,**

Estoy intentando mostrar un archivo excel (.xls) en un iframe. Con un archivo (.pdf) muestra bien; sin embargo, **el archivo excel no lo muestra en el Iframe, *directo se descarga***. Mencionar además, que en el iframe sólo sale una pantalla en blanco y ***no sale ningún error*** (simplemente no muestra nada en el iframe, directo se descarga el excel; y la idea es mostrar en el IFrame el excel) . Si alguien le ha sucedido algo parecido espero pueda orientarme. **Nota:** Estoy trabajando con aspx. y por el lado del servidor con visual basic (.aspx.vb).

[image: Imagen]

**De antemano, gracias por sus comentarios**

Comment: Tal vez es esto lo que estás buscando. Creo, no estoy seguro al 100%, que dichos archivos no se puedan visualizar así como así en una página. Deberías exportarlos. https://www.calvert.ch/maurice/2012/01/13/convert-excel-to-html-with-formatting/

Comment: Gracias compañero Zander, muy acertado tu comentario.